# IOS How to get complete URL of current selected audio track in IPHONE in MPMediaPickerController

Tags: iphone, ios

In following this method

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
```

i can get the current selected audio file

MY question is How to get complete URL for this selected audio track

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
  MPMediaItem * item = (MPMediaItem *)[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex:index];
  NSURL * pathURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
}
```